# Why does force between plate capacitors not change when dielectric is inserted between them?

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

I was told in my physics class that the force does not change between the two plates but wouldnt the electric field not change between them bc it gets divided by the dielectric constant?Hence the force should change as well. Why this does not happen?

Comment: What type of force were they talking about? This would help a lot in the due explanation. Because when we say that force between capacitors reduces due to dielectric we implicitly mean of the net force. Whereas your teacher might be talking about the the force due to one on another (not considering the other forces).

Answer (score 3):

The force will decrease if the capacitor is charged and not connected to a voltage source when the dielectric is inserted. The force will remain the same if the charged capacitor is connected to a voltage source when the dielectric is inserted. The following is by way of explanation.

The force between the plates of a charged capacitor is

$$F=QE$$

Where $Q$ is the net charge on each capacitor plate and $E$ is the electric field between the plates.

Inserting a dielectric between the plates of a capacitor reduces the effective electric field $E$ between the plates and increases the capacitance of the capacitor. If the charge $Q$ on the capacitor plates is fixed, which would be the case if the capacitor were disconnected from a voltage source (conservation of charge), then per the above equation the force will be lower.

However, if the capacitor is connected to a fixed voltage source (e.g., battery) of voltage $V$, the increase in capacitance is means the battery will separate more charge $Q$ on the plates for the same voltage because the relationship between charge, voltage and capacitance is

$$C=\frac{Q}{V}$$

So, although the electric field is reduced by inserting the dielectric, if the voltage is fixed the charge is increased by the same factor so the force between the plates (first equation) remains the same.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please tell that Am I correct to conclude this : Case-1(when no voltage source is present) (a)-Charge is same on plates(b)-Capacitance is increased(c)-potential difference between plates, field and force is reduced by factor of K (d)-Energy is increased     Case-2(when voltage source is there) (a)-charge is increased (b)-Capacitance is increased (c)-potential difference between plates, field and force is unchanged (d)- Energy is constant. Please reply that is it correct or not. Please clear my confusion. I am confused from many days.

Comment: @Shiva Case-1 (d)Energy is decreased, not increased. $C=Q/V$. Since $Q$ is constant and $C$ increases, $V$ must decrease. For example if $C$ doubles $V$ halves. Energy is $$E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$$. Doubling $C$ and halving $V$ gives $$E=\frac{1}{2}(2C)(V/2)^2=\frac{1}{4}CV^2$$ The energy is halved.

Comment: Case-2(d) Energy is increased, not constant. If $C$ increases and potential difference $V$ remains the same, $E=\frac{1}{2}CV^2$ increases. Hope this helps.

Comment: It means that other cases are correct and only what I mentioned about energy was wrong . Now you've corrected me. Absolutely, it helped me!

Comment: @Shiva In re-reading your comment something else appears incorrect. Case 2-(c) force is increased. The electric field is the same (since E=V/d  with V and d unchanged) but since Q is increased and F=QE that means F is increased.

Comment: Oops yes, thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon whether the plates have been inserted while the capacitor remains connected to the battery or while it is removed.
If the battery is still connected, the force becomes the original force times the dielectric constant.
If the battery has been disconnected, the force becomes the original force divided by the dielectric constant.
So yeah, in general, the force does change.

Comment: Hi, please substantiate these statements with a bit of math to show how these changes in force are taking place.